# Нужна ли запятая

Tags: пунктуация

"Мне не было интересно() кто она и чем занимается."

Comment: @LKa, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне не было интересно, кто она и чем занимается.

Это сложноподчиненное предложение с двумя придаточными  изъяснительными, связанными одиночным союзом И. Обычно в СПП с придаточными изъяснительными используется союзная связь (союз ЧТО и др.), но здесь функцию союзного средства выполняют относительные местоимения КТО и ЧЕМ.

Answer (score 3):

> Нужна ли запятая

НУЖНА. Разделяет части сложно-подчинённого предложения.